# MySQL - Passing UTC timestamps to sprocs via JDBC

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc, timezone

I have a MySQL Server set to UTC (@@global.time_zone = '+00:00') and a table with a DATETIME column in which I store dates in UTC. I'm having problems getting UTC dates to come through when I call a stored procedure via JDBC. Example:

```
java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
sproc = conn.prepareCall("{call TzTestInsert(?)}");
sproc.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(now.getTime()), Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+00:00")));
sproc.execute();
```

The TzTestInsert sproc simply takes a DATETIME and inserts it into the table.

I'd expect the database to now hold my current time in UTC, but in fact it holds the current time for my timezone.

If I change the sproc to take a string it works...

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
...
sproc.setString(1, dateFormat.format(now));
```

but I'd rather use the correct type in the sproc.

Also works if I bypass the sproc, but again not my preferred solution...

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO TzTest VALUES('" + dateFormat.format(now) + "') ;
```

With the original sproc I have the same issue if I use a TIMESTAMP datatype in the sproc and table, which isn't surprising with the server in UTC since any timezone conversions specific to MySQL TIMESTAMP should be noops.

Calling the sproc from a MySQL Workbench connection works fine, e.g.

```
CALL TzTestInsert(UTC_TIMESTAMP());
```

Seems like the problem is in JDBC. I've looked at the various timezone connection parameters and haven't found any that make a difference.

I must be missing something basic - lots of people do this, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to pass the JDBC driver "useLegacyDatetimeCode=false". See mysql bug http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15604

Looks like they left the old code in the driver for backwards compatibility.